# Is it possible to recover deleted text messages after a factory reset on LG Optimus One 2.2.1?

Tags: sms

I have never backed up anything off my phone. The text messages I need are from within the last month. The factory reset was done a week ago..

Answer (score 2):

Alas, the SMS are all gone, they're part of the data that gets wiped along with the factory reset.

There's no way to get them back (if you haven't backed them up at some time)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to recover the deleted SMS from android phone. Have a try.

1. Connect your Android phone and enable USB debugging
2. Analyze your Android phone

   After the USB debugging, reconnect your phone if you are asked to disconnect it during the setting.Here you need to bear in mind that your phone's battery is more than 20% charged, and then you can click "Start" to let the program analyze your Android phone.
3. Scan your Android for deleted text messages
4. Preview and recover messages from Android
   Good luck!